# Reorder fix options for Stylecop in Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, stylecop, resharper-6.0

In Resharper, pressing Alt + Enter opens the quick fix list. For StyleCop for C#, an example of the menu that would open is the following:

**Resharper 6.0 Quick-Fix**
[image]

In Reshaper 5.0, I seem to remember the "Insert Header" option would be before Suppress. Now, the Suppress option is always the first option, so my quick method of simply hitting Alt + Enter + Enter now auto-inserts a Suppression message instead of doing what I'd like it to.

Is there a way to move the "Insert header:" option, and other similiar options, to be the first option instead of Suppress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that it is not configurable and the best option is to create an issue at http://stylecop.codeplex.com.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this if there really is no way to do it, but in the meantime I have put in an issue on StyleCop's site.

Comment: Actually I don't know whether it was a good decision to place it as answer. Maybe it would be better if it were a comment?

Comment: Well if the answer is that there is no way to do it, then it's fine, and judging from the lack of responses, you could be right: http://stylecop.codeplex.com/discussions/282677

Comment: At the time, this was the correct answer. I submitted it to StyleCop, and they did fix it in 4.7.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed from version 4.7.1.0 of StyleCop onwards.